# Select last rows in ascending order

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to select last 5 messages in ascending order (Laravel) but I'm receiving this error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::reverse()`

This is what I've tried:

```
$messages = Conversation::find($id)->messages()->orderBy("created_at", "desc")->take(5)->reverse();
```

Comment: you want last or first 5 messages then?

Comment: Isn't ``reverse()`` a Collection method, rather than a db one? If so, you'll need to ``get()`` the results after the ``take(5)`` since the query isn't actually executed, just prepared, in your above code.

Comment: @JoelHinz Yes you are right, this works: $messages = Conversation::find($id)->messages()->orderBy("created_at", "desc")->take(5)->get()->reverse();   Thank you

Comment: Using 'asc' wasn't the same?

Comment: He wants the last 5 users so it means he has to sort by desc to get them.  But he wants those last 5 in ascending order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't ever running the query. The `take()` method is a query builder method rather than a return method.

- `get()` Is a return method, it will run the query return a collection
- `first()` Is a return method, it will run the query and return a model instance

It's also worth noting that `reverse()` is a collection method, so to fix your code, you'd need to do the following:

```
$messages = Conversation::find($id)->messages()->orderBy("created_at", "desc")->take(5)->get()->reverse();
```

That will work perfectly, although I would recommend checking the value before actually running a method on it, but other than that, you're good to go.